# How to fix maven-shade-plugin error: Access denied

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I want to compile a Minecraft Spigot plugin in JetBrains IntelliJ. The whole thing is done with the help of Maven. But that doesn't really work yet. Every time I want to compile it comes to this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (default) on project Kizume-RPG: Error creating shaded jar: C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Plugins (Zugriff verweigert) -> [Help 1]
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>de.lenjee</groupId>
<artifactId>Kizume-RPG</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Kizume RPG</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <outputFile>C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Plugins</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Maybe somebody knows the error. I already googled it, but the solutions are not worked for me.

Comment: The configured output directory is not allowed to be written `C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Plugins (Zugriff verweigert)` this implies this. You should not change those output directory. simply remove the configuration for that and build your project another time...

Comment: This works for me, thank you. But is there any other way, to give IntelliJ permissions to write in this directory?

Comment: The permission is handled by your operation system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<outputFile>C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Plugins</outputFile>
```

I found that you must specify the java file for it to work, that did the trick for me.
You only put the folder, and that seems to be the problem. What I mean by putting the file:

```
<outputFile>C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Plugins\Plugin.java</outputFile>
```

Instead of "Plugin.java" you can just put the name you want for your file.
I know this is late, but it's for anyone like me who struggled to find an easier solution.
Hope this helps anyone still having this issue!